# C++ templates involving vectors

Tags: c++, templates, vector, iterator, quicksort

I am working on a generic code for quick sort using vectors. I have written a code but on compiling it shows an error. The code is as follows :

```
# include <vector>
# include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
typename vector<T>::iterator partition(typename vector<T>::iterator begin,     typename vector<T>::iterator end) {
    if(begin == end){
        return end;
    }
    typedef typename vector<T>::iterator iter;
    iter pivot = begin;
    iter split = begin;
    std::advance(begin,1);
    for(iter I = begin; I != end; std::advance(I,1)){
        if(*I <= *pivot){
            std::advance(split,1);
            std::swap(*I,*split);
        }
    }
    std::swap(*split, *pivot);
    return split;
    }

template <typename T>
void quicksort(typename vector<T>::iterator begin, typename vector<T>::iterator end) {
    if(2>std::distance(begin,end)){
        return;
    }

    typename vector<T>::iterator middle = partition(begin,end);
    quicksort(begin,middle);
    std::advance(middle,1);
    quicksort(middle,end);
    }

int main(){
    vector<int> v(100);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        v[i] = rand();
    vector<int>::iterator begin = v.begin();
    vector<int>::iterator end = v.end();
    quicksort(begin,end);
    vector<int>::iterator itr = v.begin();
    while (itr != v.end()) {
        cout << *itr << " ";
        itr++;
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The error shown is as follows :

```
QuickVector.cpp:43:5: error: no matching function for call to 'quicksort'
quicksort(begin,end);
^~~~~~~~~
QuickVector.cpp:26:6: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template
  argument 'T'
void quicksort(typename vector<T>::iterator begin, typename vector<T>::i...
     ^
1 error generated.
```

Can someone help me figure out where am I going wrong? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is the error message not clear? Deduction fails here.

Do `void quicksort(T begin, T end)` instead!

Comment: I made the changes but now it shows some other errors.


`QuickVector.cpp:32:5: error: no matching function for call to 'quicksort'
    quicksort(begin,middle);
    ^~~~~~~~~
QuickVector.cpp:43:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'quicksort<std::__1::__wrap_iter<int *> >' requested here
    quicksort(begin,end);
    ^
QuickVector.cpp:26:6: note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting
      types for parameter 'T' ('__wrap_iter<int *>' vs. '__wrap_iter<class
      std::__1::__wrap_iter<int *> *>')
void quicksort(T begin, T end) {`
     ^
Can you help?

Comment: Without a testcase? No.